# not able to get classic web role using Service Principle in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net

The below code works where the authentication works. But when I try to use Service Principle as authentication the authentication fails.

**Working Script:**

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext(azureAdUrl + azureADTenant);
var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(azureUsername, azurePassword);
var authParam = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.RefreshSession, null);
var tokenInfo = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", azureADClientId, credential);

TokenCloudCredentials tokencreds = new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, tokenInfo.Result.AccessToken);

ComputeManagementClient computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(tokencreds);
string deploymentName = computeClient.Deployments.GetBySlot(serviceName, DeploymentSlot.Production).Name;
string label = computeClient.Deployments.GetBySlot(serviceName, DeploymentSlot.Production).Label;
```

**Not Working:**

> AuthenticationFailed: The JWT token does not contain expected audience
>   uri 'https://management.core.windows.net/'.

```
ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(applicationClientID, accessKey);
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + AzureTenantId);
var tokenInfo = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", cc);

tokenInfo.Wait();

if (tokenInfo == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
}

TokenCloudCredentials tokencreds = new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, tokenInfo.Result.AccessToken);

ComputeManagementClient computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(tokencreds);
string deploymentName = computeClient.Deployments.GetBySlot(serviceName, DeploymentSlot.Production).Name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to access classic Azure resources using a `Service Principal`.

Classic Azure resources are managed via `Service Management API` that does not have any notion of `Service Principal`. It only supports tokens when the token is obtained for an Administrator or Co-Administrator.

You would need to use username/password of an actual user to work with Service Management API.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I tested it on my side and could encounter the same issue as you provided. And Gaurav Mantri has provided the reasonable answer. AFAIK, for classic Azure Services (ASM), you could refer to [Authenticate using a management certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx#bk_cert) and upload a [management API certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-api-management-certs).

Here is my code snippet, you could refer to it:

```html
CertificateCloudCredentials credential = new CertificateCloudCredentials("<subscriptionId>",GetStoreCertificate("<thumbprint>"));
ComputeManagementClient computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credential);
string deploymentName = computeClient.Deployments.GetBySlot("<serviceName>", DeploymentSlot.Production).Name;
```

**Result:**

[image]